# How do I find the rule name for a TS error like TS6059?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I've got a TS6059 error:

[image]

> TS6059: File '/...' is not under 'rootDir' '...'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

I want to disable that rule for the whole file, but you can't disable by TS#, you can only disable by name. Googling for TS6509 gives a bunch of questions on this site. I don't see a master list of rule numbers to rule names.

What I don't want:

- the name of this specific rule, better to teach people where to find the mapping of rule name to rule number
- how to disable TS rules for that line
- how to disable TS rules for the whole file
- to refactor my code to fix the error, the code is fine
- to change my rootDir setting

How do I:

1. find the rule name for a TS# rule so I can disable it for the whole file
2. alternately, disable the rule by TS# for the whole file (maybe I missed how to do this)

Comment: _"you can only disable by name"_ - can you? That's a _TypeScript_ error, not ESLint.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have "rule names" corresponding to warnings, I think.  TS doesn't let you turn off warnings by id number either, see [ms/TS#29950](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29950) for the suggestion.  These numbers and messages are not guaranteed to be stable. In [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) you can toggle certain kinds of checking on and off, but there's no one-to-one mapping between these and warning id numbers.   So I guess the answer to this question is "you can't do this".

Comment: @jonrsharpe `/* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment  */`  definitely works, so are you sure "not a Typescript error" is valid?

Comment: What? Firstly I didn't say "not a Typescript error", I said "a TypeScript error". Secondly that's **not** disabling a TypeScript error, it's disabling an ESLint error (in the `@typescript-eslint` package, which prevents `// @ts-` comments: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-ts-comment.md).

Comment: You: "That's a TypeScript error", then you later: "Firstly I didn't say 'not a Typescript error'". -_- -- I certainly wouldn't call it an error, since the code runs fine with `@ts-ignore` (which is a Typescript directive).

Comment: What's your point? Yes, I said it's a TypeScript error, as in an error from the TypeScript compiler (which I don't believe you can disable by name or by number), **not** from ESLint (which you also tagged and which you _can_ disable by name - it seems you're confusing these with one another). You seemingly quoted me as saying "not a TypeScript error" which is precisely the opposite of what I said, and I pointed out as much - I have been consistent. I don't see why the fact that telling the compiler to ignore the error means it ignores the error makes it not an error.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is not configurable to the extent that e.g. ESLint is. You can [configure certain options via tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig), but some errors are simply that — errors which prevent valid compilation (or transpilation, if you prefer). [Here's the reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0414deeaaf211ee000548c30fd81aa09b311abb7/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L4330) for the error message in your question for example:

```json
"File '{0}' is not under 'rootDir' '{1}'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.": {
    "category": "Error",
    "code": 6059
},
```

Similar to the missing file error code a few codes up from that, `"File '{0}' not found."`, there is no configuration in which the error can be ignored and you can still be sure the compiler output makes sense.

Much like you can't be sure you won't get a runtime error after ignoring a missing file warning, you can't be sure the output makes sense if the compiler can't grok the project structure.

Comment: "there is no configuration in which the error can be ignored and a successful compilation still be made." -- Code runs fine if I add `@ts-ignore` to each line that is pulling data files from outside of `src`. It's even reading in the json structure during coding. I guess this is just a little issue between `@typescript-eslint` and Typescript itself. Doesn't look like a transpilation error to me, just a "Typescript is going out of its comfort zone here".

Comment: @jcollum I don't really agree with that take, but I think my wording might've not been the best. Compilation might happen, but it can't be guaranteed to be valid might be a better wording perhaps. Reusing the missing file analogy, you can `@ts-ignore` a missing file and compile, but then get a runtime error when you actually try to do something with it. To put another way, you can compile nearly anything if you ignore every line, doesn't mean it will end up making any sense.